# joomla component 1.5 to joomla component 1.6

Tags: joomla, components

Hello
I have some knowledge of joomla component development.
i want to know that what is a basic change require for joomla 1.5 component to joomla component 1.6 .

have any have any idea kindly replay me.

Comment: That is not a specific, problem-centric question. (Check the FAQ on what to ask on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

There is [a wiki page for that on Joomlas docs wiki](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6).

Although it does not seem to be complete just yet, it should help you out.

Your component may even just work without any changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are muchos changes in Form input handling, and definition. Also, the installation xml file has changed. The general consensus in the Joomla! community seems to be wait until the next release due in June 2011. Ive even seen Joomla! Devs reccomending people start new Websites in Joomla! 1.5.. Conclusion: you might want to hold off for a bit! ;D